# Undefined control sequence - Math mode, \hat

Tags: errors, lyx

I received a LyX file from my friend and when I tried to compile it, LyX showed me this these errors.
[image: Undefined control sequence]

I have no idea what is going on. Hope you can help me out, thanks a lot.

**Update:** Here is the minimal example and I'm using LyX 2.1.3, thanks for your help.
https://goo.gl/JTKzXV

Comment: The undefined control sequence is `\textdegree`, that requires loading the `textcomp` package.

Comment: Can you please post a minimal example of this? This could be a LyX bug. Ideally, LyX should load the package for you. If you post the .lyx file we can fix the bug at the source. Either post the .lyx file here and I'll take a look at it or open a bug report at http://www.lyx.org/trac. Please also put what LyX version you are using.

Comment: @scottkosty I've posted it, hope you can help. Thank you. :)

Comment: @Danbo3004 Thank you for posting the file. However, it is not a minimal example. For more information, please see http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample . Next time, please post a minimal example. I was able to make a minimal example from your file. I think this is indeed a LyX bug. I will look into it. For now, you can just add `\usepackage{textcomp}` at Document > Settings > LaTeX Preamble. Does that work?

Comment: @egreg can you make an answer saying to put `\textdegree` in the preamble? Don't forget to add to your answer "This is another reason why you shouldn't use LyX" :)

Comment: @scottkosty Probably you know the right LyX way.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug in LyX. LyX is supposed to automatically load the right packages (unless you use ERT, then you're on your own). For some reason, when the document is set to Vietnamese, the package is not loaded automatically. To work around this bug, go to Document > Settings > LaTeX Preamble and put the following:

```
\usepackage{textcomp}
```